# Function to validate an input type button max value 9 and min value 1, not working

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a challenge that make a table depending on what's on the inputs.

```js
function createTable(){
    let table = document.getElementById('table')
    let row = document.getElementById('input-row').value
    let column = document.getElementById('input-column').value

     for(let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < row; rowIndex++){
        let tr = document.createElement('tr')

        for(let colIndex = 0; colIndex < column; colIndex++){
            let td = document.createElement('td')
            tr.appendChild(td)
        }

        table.appendChild(tr)

        document.getElementById('input-row').value = " "
        document.getElementById('input-column').value = " "

        if(row == " ") {
            alert('Number of rows cannot be empty')
            return false
        }

        if(row > 9) {
            alert('Number of rows cannot be greater than 9')
            return false
        }

        if(row <= 0) {
            alert('Number of rows cannot be less than 1')
            return false
        }
      
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="inputs-container">
            <div class="inputs-container_rows">
                <input type="number" class="inputs" max=9 min=0 id="input-row" maxlength="1">
                <h3>Rows</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="inputs-container_columns">
                <input type="number" class="inputs" max=9 min=0 id="input-column">
                <h3>Columns</h3>
            </div>
 </div>
 <div class="btn-container">
            <button id="btn" onclick="createTable()">Create Table</button>
        </div>
        <div class="table-container">
            <table border="1" id="table">

            </table>
 </div>
```

for the validation only the if(row > 9) is working the other ones not.

Also, I want to erase the table when again I press the button, I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed some issues:

1. Since you get the `row` value as a `string`, you should use the `String.length` property to check if it is empty. Or you can evaluate that no value is entered by comparing with `""`.
2. You need to convert `row` to integer before comparing; `parseInt()` method can be used for this purpose.
3. You should evaluate conditions before looping.

```js
let table = document.getElementById('table');
let rowElement = document.getElementById('input-row');
let columnElement = document.getElementById('input-column');

function isValid() {
    let row = rowElement.value;
    
    if(row.length == 0){
        alert('Number of rows cannot be empty');
        return false;
    }

    if(parseInt(row) > 9) {
        alert('Number of rows cannot be greater than 9');
        return false;
    }

    if(parseInt(row) <= 0) {
        alert('Number of rows cannot be less than 1');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function createTable(){
    let row = rowElement.value;
    let column = columnElement.value;

    if(isValid(row))
    {
      for(let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < row; rowIndex++)
      {
          let tr = document.createElement('tr')

          for(let colIndex = 0; colIndex < column; colIndex++){
              let td = document.createElement('td')
              tr.appendChild(td)
          }

          table.appendChild(tr);
          document.getElementById('input-row').value = "";
          document.getElementById('input-column').value = "";
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="inputs-container">
  <div class="inputs-container_rows">
      <input type="number" class="inputs" max=9 min=0 id="input-row" maxlength="1">
      <h3>Rows</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="inputs-container_columns">
      <input type="number" class="inputs" max=9 min=0 id="input-column">
      <h3>Columns</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="btn-container">
  <button id="btn" onclick="createTable()">Create Table</button>
</div>

<div class="table-container">
  <table border="1" id="table"></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have anything that requires user interaction, you'll need to listen for events (unless you are using `prompt()` but that's just plain awful). The "click" event is the goto event but there are far better ones you could use especially if you use a `<form>`. One event in particular is exclusively for the form:

- `submit`: When user is focused in a field and hits
  <kbd>Enter/Return</kbd> key or a `<button>`,
  `<input type="submit">`, or
  `<input type="image">` is clicked the form will:

  - validate itself if there is any `[required]`, `[pattern]`, `[min]`, `[max]`, etc. attributes or any validation methods hooked in,
  - gather all values from any fields with a `[name]` attribute,
  - then send it to a server, and will return a response.

If it doesn't have a server to send it to, it will return a blank page. The example below will do everything when a "submit" event is fired, but it will not send data to a server. You should read the following:

- [Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)
- [Event Delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)
- [Inline Event Handlers are Garbage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these)
- [Forms and Form Controls (aka Fields)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement)

***Details are commented in the example below***

```js
/***********
    ** Creates a given element and appends them.
    * @param   {String}     tag     tagName of element to be 
    *                               created
    * @param   {DOM Object} parent  DOM object to append to
    * @param   {Number}     times   number of times tag is 
    *                               created
    * @param   {String}     content string in 
    *                               each cell (Default is empty)
    * @returns {DOM Object|Array} DOM object or an array of DOM 
    *                             objects
    */
    const setDOM = (tag, parent, times, content = '') => {
      let nodeList = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        let node = document.createElement(tag);
        parent.appendChild(node);
        node.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', content);
        nodeList.push(node);
      }
      return times > 1 ? nodeList : times === 1 ? nodeList.pop() : null;
    }
    
    /** Event handler passes an Event Object (e) **/
    const buildTable = e => {
    
      /** Event Properties/Methods 
      -Stop normal behavior of form submits
      -(io) is all form controls (fieldset, legend, input, 
      button)
      */
      e.preventDefault();
      const io = e.currentTarget.elements;
      
      /** Form Data 
      -(r) number of rows
      -(c) number of columns
      -(cnt) text if any from #edit
      */
      let r = parseInt(io.rows.value);
      let c = parseInt(io.cols.value);
      let cnt = io.edit.innerHTML;
      
      /** Create the Table 
      -Clear #box
      -Create <table> in #box
      -Create <tbody> in table
      */      
      io.box.replaceChildren();
      const table = setDOM('table', io.box, 1);
      const tB = setDOM('tbody', table, 1);
      
      /** Create Rows & Columns
      -Create all <tr>
      -if an array is returned...
        ...Use .forEach() to create the <td> for each <tr>...
        ...Otherwise just run setDOM() once to create the <td>
      */
      const allRows = setDOM('tr', tB, r);
      if (Array.isArray(allRows)) {
        allRows.forEach((row, idx) => setDOM('td', allRows[idx], c, cnt));
      } else {
        setDOM('td', allRows, c, cnt);
      }
      
      /** Create tHead 
      -if #head is checked...
        ...Create <thead>...
        ...Create <tr>...
        ...Create all <th>
      */
      if (io.head.checked) {
        let tH = table.createTHead();
        let hRow = setDOM('tr', tH, 1);
        setDOM('th', hRow, c, cnt);
      }
      
      /** Create tFoot 
      -if #foot is checked...
        ...Create <tfoot>...
        ...Create <tr>...
        ...Create all <td>
      */
      if (io.foot.checked) {
        let tF = table.createTFoot();
        let fRow = setDOM('tr', tF, 1);
        setDOM('td', fRow, c, cnt);
      }
    };
    
    // Reference the form and listen for the submit event
    const UI = document.forms[0];
    UI.onsubmit = buildTable;
```

```css
*, *::before {box-sizing: border-box;}:root {font: 1ch/1.25 'Segoe UI';}body {font-size: 4ch;}.box {width: 100%;max-width: max-content;background: lightgrey;}.box:empty {border: 0;background: transparent;}.edit {width: 100%;min-width: 50vw;min-height: 50px;overflow-wrap: break-word;word-break: break-word;border: 0;outline: 0;padding: 0;}.group {display: flex;flex-flow: row wrap;justify-content: flex-start;align-items: center;}fieldset, button, input {border-radius: 4px;}input {display: inline-block;font-size: 100%;font-family: Consolas;}label {display: flex;align-items: center;margin-right: 2rem;margin-top: 4px;font-size: 100%;}label b {font-weight: 400;}button {display: block;float: right;width: 80px;margin: 4px 0;font-size: 100%;cursor: pointer;}.num {width: 5ch;}.chx {width: 15px;height: 15px;margin-bottom: -1px;cursor: pointer;}table {table-layout: fixed;border-collapse: collapse;width: 100%;}table, td, th {border: 1px solid #000;}th {background: lime;}tbody td {background: cyan;}tfoot td {background: tomato;}
```

```html
<main>
    <form id='UI'>
      <fieldset>
        <fieldset class='group'>
          <legend>Rows &amp; Columns</legend>
          <label>Rows:......<sup>(max. 99)</sup>&nbsp;
          <input id='rows' class='num' type='number' min='1' max='99' maxlegnth='3' required></label>
          <label>Columns:.<sup>(max. 20)</sup>&nbsp;
          <input id='cols' class='num' type='number' min='1' max='20' maxlegnth='3' required></label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Optional text </legend>
          <fieldset id='edit' class='edit' contenteditable></fieldset>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class='group'>
          <legend>Optional Sections</legend>
          <label><b>Table Head:</b>&nbsp;<input id='head' class='chx' type='checkbox'></label>
          <label><b>Table Foot:</b>&nbsp;<input id='foot' class='chx' type='checkbox'></label>
        </fieldset>
        <button>GO</button>
        <fieldset id='box' class='box'></fieldset>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </main>
```